# Import saved places to native android application from google maps

Tags: android, web-services, api, google-maps, google-places

I have been searching for a longtime  how to import my saved places on google maps to my android application programmatically using google maps api for android, until now i haven't found any results, i need your help guys to solve this.

[here the list of my saved places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX8ZF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot do it straight because there is not an API. Google provides an API for saving location to MyMaps but not for retrieving.

[click here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-infowindow)

A dump way is to give instruction to each user, to download its place [from google share data](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout), and upload the .json file with MyPlaces.